# How to disable the browser Forward button using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a quiz application in which there are five different pages. I have handled session and prevent back button after login. But I am quite new to javascript, so how to disable the browser forward button. i.e. if the user is in QuizPage1.jsp, he/she should not access forward button in the browser..They have to press the submit button after answering those quizes. I checked many questions in stackoverflow regarding this. But, I found solution for disabling back button only. 
So, Your help is highly appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

[image]

Comment: Isn't the forward button only enabled after you click the back button? If you have already prevented the user from using the back button why would you need to disable the forward button?

Comment: In some pages only I have disabled the back button. In some pages, forward buttons are there...I need to disable those forward buttons

Answer (score -2):

Forward button is automatically useless if you disable the back button. I don't think the forward button does what you think it does. You can't jump to pages you haven't visited before by using the forward button, so no-one can use it to skip pages (as you seem to think would happen).

Also - do not disable the back button. If I ever see the back button disabled, it is a guaranteed way never to see me on your page again.

Comment: I can understand..Lets take this scenario. I have 3 jsp pages. I am accessing first one, it is redirected to second jsp page, then from second jsp, it is redirected to third jsp. Again I am clicking browser back button. Now second jsp page is displayed. As mentioned in the picture, it is showing browser forward button, if i click the forward button, it should not go to third jsp page. This is what I need.

Comment: You said you prevented the back button; how is the user going back to the second jsp?

Comment: In some pages only I have disabled the back button. In some pages, forward buttons are there...I need to disable those forward buttons